# поиск в базе по значениям в разных строках

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица в которой хранятся значения полей.

Она имеет 3 поля: `object_id`, `field_id`, `value`

Например, у товара 3 параметра: цвет, цена и вес. Для каждого параметра будет создана своя строка в таблице.

Вопрос: реально ли искать по 2м параметрам (т.е. по значениям из разных строк), если MySQL ищет построчно?

Comment: *реально ли искать по 2м параметрам* Да, реально. Модель хранения называется EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value). Почитайте про неё и типовые операции на ней. *если MySQL ищет построчно?* Сервер ищет НЕ построчно. Но это Вам и не нужно знать, как именно он это делает.

Answer (score 0):

Да можно напиши 2 **AND** например:  `where цвет = 'blue' AND цена = '$2'`   
а если нужен один из них напиши так: `where 1 AND (цвет = 'blue' OR цена = '$2')`